# Wordpress won't display image and link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem with getting the link and image when the given field "pdf" exists. It doesn't show the image, and the link doesn't display the `href` tag.

```
<?php if(the_field('pdf'))
 echo '<a href="'.the_field('pdf').'"> <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory')?>.'"/img/pdf_icon.png"/> </a>';
?>
```

Comment: Try replacing .get_bloginfo('template_directory')?>. with .get_bloginfo('template_directory').

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more information?! How do you mean it doesnt show when 'pdf' exist? 
Put this code, and tell us the output

```
<?php if(the_field('pdf'))
{
   echo "pdf do NOT exist";
   echo '<a href="'.the_field('pdf').'"> <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory')?>.'"/img/pdf_icon.png"/> </a>';
}
else
{
   echo "Success - pdf do exist";
   echo '<a href="'.the_field('pdf').'"> <img  src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory')?>.'"/img/pdf_icon.png"/> </a>';
}

?>
```

Comment: It dosen't work, and for some reason, the link is outside of a a href tag, it only has to display the pdf image, when user has uploaded a pdf file, it there is just text, it shouldn't show the pdf image